# Why is enumerate files returning the same file more than once?

Tags: c#, winforms, io, .net

I have this code (thanks to those that have been helping so far)

It searches through a directory and all subdirectories looking for a file names.

```
Files.Clear(); //BindingList<FileInfo> Datasource for a datagridview

Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
       DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MainFolder);

       foreach(var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*" + textBox1.Text + "*.doc?", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Take(200))
       {
          this.BeginInvoke( new Action(() =>
             {
                Files.Add(file);
             }));
       }
     });
```

The problem is if I set `textBox1.text` to something I know there is only 1 of, it adds it to `Files` 4 times. I tried break pointing it to be certain it wasn't in how I was displaying it.

I compared the 4 objects to each other, they are identical. When I open up the search criteria a little and get 5 results, some of them are 1 some are doubles some triples. so there are 5 unique results but there is a total of about 10-12.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Invoke.

Your lambda is capturing the variable file which is being mutated. You are not only getting duplicates, you are also missing files.

Comment: Can you be a little clearer, I didn't write most of the above code, and While I am playing with it, and it's making far more sense, can you show me where the file variable is being mutated, cause I thought I was using invoke.

Comment: BeginInvoke is calling your lambda concurrently with you file enumeration code. Once the next loop iteration has started the variable file contains the next file. But your lambda expected the old one. A different solution is to copy file into a local variable first.

Comment: I changed the BeginInvoke to Invoke and it seems to have solved it.  I will have to research their differences

Comment: Invoke only returns after your code has fully run. That way it doesn't matter if the variable file is mutated later. We needed to prevent it being mutated concurrently (unpredictably).

Answer (score 0):

you are directly using the enumeration variable

if you copy the variable to a local variable, it should be fine

Files.Clear(); //BindingList Datasource for a datagridview

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MainFolder);
        foreach(var file in dir.EnumerateFiles("*"+textBox1.Text+"*.doc?",SearchOption.AllDirectories).Take(200))
        {
            var currentFile = file;
            this.BeginInvoke( new Action(() =>
            {
                Files.Add(currentFile);
            }));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Sounds good but file.Clone() isn't an option. and I am using the file variable as a FileInfo, so I can't cast it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

This should work faster and have better clarity.

```
var searchPattern = "*" + textBox1.Text + "*.doc?";
Files.Clear(); //BindingList<FileInfo> Datasource for a datagridview
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(MainFolder);
Files.AddRange(dir.EnumerateFiles(searchPatten, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList());
```

Why initially did you use all the async operations??

Comment: Because it was freezing the program, while it searched.  It was taking 10 seconds or so.